# Running tensorflow unit tests

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

After cloning the tensorflow repo, running its configure.py, I run

```
$ bazel test //tensorflow/...
```

and receive this error

```
ERROR: /Users/aidangoldfarb/Projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39/BUILD:36:11: in interpreter_path attribute of py_runtime rule //tensorflow/tools/toolchains/win_1803/py39:py3_runtime: must be an absolute path.
```

My goal is to fix a bug I found in the AOT compiler. I would like to verify the correctness of my changes.

I am running on MacBook Air with M2, macOS 13.4, and Xcode 15

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you get the error wehn the Bazel test is running after the repo clone it an configuring it.

Issue in 'interepter_path' of 'py_runtime' in file ''BUILD.

to fix the error try to have the dependencies and tools installed by TensorFlow documentation. It has Bazel,Python ..

Check the 'BUILD' file and locate the rle of 'py_runtime' and be sure that the attribute of the rule comtains an absolute path of python interpreter.

save the commits changes in the BUILD  and run the Bazel test again.